# How to disable sleep mode in Fedora 18

Tags: linux, fedora

After every 10 minutes my laptop go to sleep mode. I can't find an option to disable this. Please help.

Comment: It should be under power options in gnome-settings. Have a look around.

Comment: I check "System parameters" - "Power". Then i set to "Never" in "Put computer to sleep when inactive for" option, but nothing changes. After 10 minutes laptop go to sleep mode.

Comment: Are you sure the laptop is going to sleep or is the monitor shutting off to save battery life?